# Bash: Using Python-function Ceil - How to do ceil of the product of two variables?

Tags: python, bash

I tried to run the following code, which is inside of a Bash-script.

```
NUMBER=600
LOSS_RATE=0,3
TOT_PKT=100

test=$(python -c "from math import ceil; print ceil($NUMBER * 500.0)")
test2=$(python -c "from math import ceil; print ceil($NUMBER * $LOSS_RATE)")
echo $test
echo $test2
```

I get the following printed out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ceil() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
300000.0
```

The first Python-command is executed, but the second causes the given TypeError. How do I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses `.` as the decimal point since `,` is the argument separator. So if you use `LOSS_RATE=0.3` everything should work fine:

```
> NUMBER=600
> LOSS_RATE=0.3
> python -c "from math import ceil; print ceil($NUMBER * $LOSS_RATE)"
180.0
```

<strike>The problem lies in the shell script. `echo` instead of `python -c` the code and you'll see it:</strike>

```
> echo "from math import ceil; print ceil($NUMBER * $LOSS_RATE)"
from math import ceil; print ceil(600 * )
```

You never define `LOSS_RATE`. However, this results in a SyntaxError. Since you get a different error it sounds like `LOSS_RATE` is set to something containing a comma.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I have defined this in the shell script:
LOSS_RATE=0,3
Sorry for missing to include this above!

Comment: There we go. Use `.` instead of `,` - i don't think there's any serious programming language where `,` is the decimal point.